# scrolling an element on top of a fixed element

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a fixed element that other elements scroll on top of instead of underneath..

like here I would like "text" to scroll up on top of the white box instead of being covered by it

```css
html{
  background: grey;  
}

.white{
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.space
```

```html
<div class='white'></div>
<div><br><br><br>text</div>
<div style="height:1000px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use z-index.

So .white would be a z-index:100 and then add a class to your text div with a z-index:101